# Setting specific value to jira item in the backlog overview

Tags: jira, jira-agile

[I've marked following components that I want to enable. For instance I want to add it from scratch and add labels, components, fix versions , story poibts, release versions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErWcx.png)

My question is how can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'add it from scratch'? You could import stories from a csv file and include all the data you want to populate those fields.

Comment: For instance if i do not want to include story and link stiry but i want to show release version or another issue attribute(s)

Comment: You know that you can configure which fields are in each issue type? You can also configure which fields show up on various screens, such as the edit issue screen. It that what you are after, customising the fields that are displayed?

Comment: I do not know the place where I can manage components (the question onlu about showing different components) in each item of backlog list as was shown in the 1st pic (1st message ). Do you know it exact ?

Comment: OK, I think I understand. You are asking how you can configure what fields are shown in the view in your screen shot. I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that. I am not aware of any way of changing the fields displayed in that view.

Comment: Spent time to explain for sure....